# Java, from XMPP server response string to XML Document

Tags: java, xml, string, xmpp, document

I have a client which connects to a XMPP Server, and the server send me the answer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><stream:stream id="119B61FB" from="chat.facebook.com" version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xml:lang="en">
```

I try to create an `XMLDocument` with the `Document` class:

```
try {
        parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        d = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(cleanXMLString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(XMPPManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(XMPPManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

but I get the error:

> `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity of the SAXException.`

There is a way to disable this restriction, because it is normal that the document is not closed by a `</stream:stream>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first of many questions that you will have implementing XMPP.

You'll need an incremental XML parser, like James Clark's [XP](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xp/).  Even better would be to use an existing XMPP library for Java from the [list on xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried a demo and I saw thet there is need to use a valid XML document. I have solved by manually adding the end tag at the string before parsing it.

Comment: That approach will work for you for several hours.  Tomorrow, after you've written a working but incorrect angle-bracket parser so that you can tell when you have what you think of as a complete document to put into the XML parser, you'll realize that you'll need a new XML parser for each stanza, which is a *ton* of memory.  Seriously, I've written multiple XMPP clients and client libs.  Heartache lies down the path you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) for communications between your server and client.  It will take care of all the low level communications for you and allow you to program at a more functional abstraction level.

Comment: In Smack api I don't know how to use a custom SASL mechanism, lie X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM.

Comment: Add your own SASL mechanism: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/SASLAuthentication.html